# Laravel Ascending order records display

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a Laravel project. I have retrieved the data from the database and I am viewing it in JSON format in ascending order. I tried the example, but it's not working. What I have tried so far is attached below.

```php
$keyword = $request->get('search');
$perPage = 25;

if (!empty($keyword)) {
    $courses = Course::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
        ->all()->paginate($perPage);
} else {
    $courses = Course::all()->paginate($perPage);
}

return response()->json($courses)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you sort afterwards? Why don't you perform the sorting with the database engine before the query?

Here you're telling Laravel to "**convert it to JSON text**", and then you want to tell the text to "**sort by the ID column**", but now we're no longer talking about arrays and objects, but rather about text, so your request doesn't make sense.

```php
response()->json($courses)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get()
```

#### Solution

```php
$keyword = $request->get('search');
$perPage = 25;

if (!empty($keyword)) {
    $courses = Course::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->paginate($perPage); // don't need ->all()
} else {
    $courses = Course::orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->paginate($perPage); // don't need ->all()

}

return response()->json($courses); // don't need ->get()
```

#### More concise, thoughtful coding

```php
$keyword = $request->get('search');
$perPage = 25;

// It's a query that hasn't been executed yet
// We're just building it to specify what we want. The query will be executed when one of the following functions is called: ->first(), ->get(), ->all(), or ->paginate()
$courses = Course::orderBy('id', 'asc');

if (!empty($keyword)) {
    // The query has still not been executed; we have just added a condition to it
    $courses = $courses->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
}

// The query was executed here using ->paginate(), and then we returned the response using response()->json()
return response()->json($courses->paginate($perPage));
```

#### Summary

###### Build Query

Firstly, we need to assemble what we want to query. For this, we can use functions like `->where()`, `->orderBy()`, `->groupBy()`, etc. You can chain them together with any logic you need.

- [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries)

###### Get Result

Once this logic is built, you can retrieve the records that match the conditions using the `->first()`, `->get()`, `->all()`, or `->paginate()` functions. This will give you an object or an array, depending on the function used. (This is already good on its own.)

###### all() or get()?

The `all()` method returns all query results as a collection, while the `get()` method only returns the results as a simple array. Therefore, **the `all()` method cannot have any direct influence or filtering applied** It can only filter the already retrieved records afterwards. This can often be problematic. Imagine a table with 10,000 rows, where you fetch all 10,000 rows and then filter out the ones with odd IDs, resulting in 5,000 records. In contrast, **using pre-filtering with the `get()` method, the database would have performed the filtering**, and the server would only receive 5,000 records instead of the full 10,000.

In my opinion, the `all()` method can be useful in very rare cases. **Database engines are capable of performing filtering and grouping operations with excellent performance, making `get()` a very practical alternative.** The all() method may provide some advantages when listing or exporting all data, but even in those cases, its usefulness is limited. **The `paginate()` method you used is a great way to avoid working with all records at once.**

- [Laravel Retrieving Models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-models)
- [Laravel Paginating Eloquent Result](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results)

It's always important to make sure that whenever possible, we only query the necessary records and minimize the number of queries executed.

###### Send with response

After that, you can transform the array/object into JSON format using `->json()` if you want to transmit it to the client side.

- [Laravel Making Request](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#making-requests)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use orderBy in not Eloquent Class. Instead, use it on Eloquent Builder.

When an eloquent builder call all() is not eloquent anymore, it is become Collection.

Try this:

```php
$perPage = 25;
$courses = Course::query();
if ($request->has('search')) {
   $courses->where('name', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->get('search') . "%");      
}
$courses->orderBy('id', 'asc');
$paginatedCourses = $courses->paginate($perPage);
return response()->json($paginatedCourses);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `orderBy` with the query, not after like the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#orderby). And `all()` will return all [results](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-models).

```
$keyword = $request->get('search');
$perPage = 25;

$query = Course::query();

if (!empty($keyword)) {
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
}

$courses = $query->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate($perPage);

return response()->json($courses);
```